# how to handle different type of value in single field of JSON payload

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I have come across a situation where I have to support existing client, they are using below payload for rest api,

```
{
  "firstName": "First name",
  "secondName": "Second name",
  "dateOfBirth": "01/12/2020",
  "profession": "Software Developer",
  "salary": 0,
  **"value": "value1"**
}
```

but now as per requirement, they may send array for value field like below :

```
{
  "firstName": "First name",
  "secondName": "Second name",
  "dateOfBirth": "01/12/2020",
  "profession": "Software Developer",
  "salary": 0,
  **"value": ["Value1", "value2", "Value3"]**
}
```

Existing code uses `@RequestBody` to convert it to `PersonDTO person`, this class also contains a method called `isMutliValue()` & `getMultiValueFor()`, and these methods splits the string based on comma then decide and return values out of it. but now for this requirement, **I have to made a modification to check if client is sending array in value or simple string. if it is a simple string then don't split it based on comma and simply process it but if it is an array, bring values out of it and send individual values.**

```
public class PersonDTO {
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
    // Formats output date when this DTO is passed through JSON
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    // Allows dd/MM/yyyy date to be passed into GET request in JSON
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    private String profession;
    private BigDecimal salary;
    private String value;

    public PersonDTO(
            String firstName, String secondName, Date dateOfBirth, String profession, BigDecimal salary, String value) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.profession = profession;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public PersonDTO() {}

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondName;
    }

    public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
        this.secondName = secondName;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession) {
        this.profession = profession;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Object value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean isMultiValued() {
        return value.split(",").length > 1;
    }

    public String[] getMultiValues() {
        return value.split(",");
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "FirstName : " + firstName +" SecondName : "+ secondName +", Value : "+ value.toString();
    }

}
```

please help me out, how can we handle **different type of values** in single field of json payload.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can implement custom deserialization. so for this purpose you should define a `PersonDTODeserializer` that extends from `JsonDeserializer` and override `deserialize` method.

```
public class PersonDTODeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {

@Override
public Object deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, 
                       DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
    JsonNode node = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
    String name = node.get("firstName").textValue();
    String secondName = node.get("secondName").textValue();
    BigDecimal salary = node.get("salary").decimalValue();
    String value = "";
    JsonNode nodeValue = node.get("value");
    if (nodeValue.isArray()) {
        Iterator<JsonNode> nodeIterator = nodeValue.iterator();
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
        while (nodeIterator.hasNext()) {
           values.add( nodeIterator.next().textValue());
        }
        value = String.join(",",values);

     } else if (nodeValue.isTextual()) {
        value = nodeValue.textValue();
     }

     return new PersonDTO(name, secondName, salary, value);
  }
}
```

and use it in `PersonDTO` class.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = PersonDTODeserializer.class)
public class PersonDTO {

   //other 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Hadi J answer,
you can set the deserializer on this field only and not the whole class :

```
public class PersonDTO {
   // ...
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ValueDeserializer.class)
    private String value;
   // ...
}
```

and the Deserializer:

```
    private static class ValueDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            if( p.isExpectedStartArrayToken() ) {
                List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>( p.readValueAs(List.class) );
                return String.join(",", values);
            } else {
                return p.getValueAsString();
            }
        }
    }
```